# How to submit forms using radio button one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, radio-button

I have multiple forms with the same id, a hidden field and a radio button.

```
<form method='post' id='check'>
    <input type='radio' name='class' value='ac'>
    <input type='hidden' name='train_no' value='12304'>
</form>
```

I'm using jquery ajax to submit a form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='class']").change(function() {                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",             
            data: $("#check").serialize(),                
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                //alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is I am unable to determine which form I need to submit as the form id for all form is the same. I need to submit one form at a time with the form data. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: I stopped reading at "I have more then one form with same id" <- ***You can't, ID's are unique*** !!

Comment: i know i realized that @adeneo so i asked for a better way of approach .

Comment: Change it to `data : $(this.form).serialize(), `

Comment: +1 that was a nice trick  @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='class']").change(function() { 
        var form = this.form; // Here is your form reference
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",             
            data: $(form).serialize(),                
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                //alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```